# Conditional probability with two inequalities

Tags: probability, integration, definite-integrals, random-variables, conditional-probability

Let $(X,Y)$ a random vector with density $f(x,y)=\frac{6}{7}(x^2+\frac{xy}{2});0<x<1,0<y<2$.

After checking that is a density, finding the marginal $f_X(x)=\frac{12}{7}x^2+\frac{6}{7}x$ and the probability $\mathbb{P}(X>Y)=\frac{15}{56}$, i have to find $\mathbb{P}(Y>\frac{1}{2}|X<\frac{1}{2})$.

I know that the domain is $0<x<\frac{1}{2}<y<2$, so i applied the conditional probability $\mathbb{P}(Y>\frac{1}{2}|X<\frac{1}{2})=\frac{\mathbb{P}((Y>\frac{1}{2})\cap (X<\frac{1}{2}))}{\mathbb{P}(X<\frac{1}{2})}$ and i tried to integrate in the most different ways…

1) $\frac{\int_{0}^{3/2}(\int_{0}^{5/2}f(x,y)dy)dx}{\int_{0}^{1/2}f_X(x)dx}$

2) $\frac{\int_{0}^{1/2}(\int_{1/2}^{2}f(x,y)dy)dx}{\int_{0}^{1/2}f_X(x)dx}$

3) ${\int_{0}^{1/2}(\int_{1/2}^{2}\frac{f(x,y)}{f_X(x)}dy)}dx$

…but to no avail.

---

### How to act when the conditional probability provides for two disequalities?

---

EDIT: Trivially, you might say "Making the graph". Well, I'm having a hard time to understand how to draw it correctly.
In the first probability that i said, the graph was fairly simple because I could use the 1°-3° bisector to separate the region to integrate.

Comment: I would at most make a graph of the support to get some orientation. Further the integration is straightforward (as you can see in my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You found correctly:
$$\int_{0}^1\int_0^2f(x,y)dydx=\int_{0}^1\int_0^2\frac{6}{7}(x^2+\frac{xy}{2}) dydx=1\\
f_X(x)=\int_0^2 \frac{6}{7}(x^2+\frac{xy}{2})dy=\frac{12}{7}x^2+\frac{6}{7}x.$$
Now, your second formula is correct:
$$\mathbb{P}(Y>\frac{1}{2}|X<\frac{1}{2})=\frac{\mathbb{P}((Y>\frac{1}{2})\cap (X<\frac{1}{2}))}{\mathbb{P}(X<\frac{1}{2})}=\\
\frac{\int_{0}^{1/2}(\int_{1/2}^{2}f(x,y)dy)dx}{\int_{0}^{1/2}f_X(x)dx}=\\
\frac{\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac67(x^2y+\frac{xy^2}{4})|_{1/2}^2dx}{\int_{0}^{1/2}(\frac{12}{7}x^2+\frac{6}{7}x)dx}=\\
\frac{\int_{0}^{1/2}(\frac97x^2+\frac{45x}{112})dx}{(\frac{4x^3}{7}+\frac{3x^2}{7})|_{0}^{1/2}}=\\
\frac{(\frac{3x^3}{7}+\frac{45x^2}{224})|_{0}^{1/2}}{5/28}=\\
\frac{69/448}{5/28}=\\
\frac{69}{80}\approx 0.8625.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

For $a\in\left[0,1\right]$ and $b\in\left[0,2\right]$ define:

$$\begin{aligned}f\left(a,b\right) & :=P\left(X<a,Y>b,\right)\\
 & =\frac{6}{7}\int_{0}^{a}\int_{b}^{2}x^{2}+\frac{1}{2}xy\;dydx\\
 & =\frac{6}{7}\int_{0}^{a}\left[x^{2}y+\frac{1}{4}xy^{2}\right]_{b}^{2}\;dx\\
 & =\frac{6}{7}\int_{0}^{a}\left(2-b\right)x^{2}+\frac{1}{4}\left(4-b^{2}\right)x\;dx\\
 & =\frac{6}{7}\left[\frac{1}{3}\left(2-b\right)x^{3}+\frac{1}{8}\left(4-b^{2}\right)x^{2}\right]_{0}^{a}\\
 & =\frac{6}{7}\left(\frac{1}{3}\left(2-b\right)a^{3}+\frac{1}{8}\left(4-b^{2}\right)a^{2}\right)\\
 & =\frac{1}{28}a^{2}\left(2-b\right)\left(8a+6+3b\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Then $P\left(X<\frac{1}{2}\right)=f\left(\frac{1}{2},0\right)$ and
$P\left(Y>\frac{1}{2},X<\frac{1}{2}\right)=f\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$
so that: $$P\left(Y>\frac{1}{2}\mid X<\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{f\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)}{f\left(\frac{1}{2},0\right)}$$

Just substitute.